# Keep the size of svg inside an html page

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf, svg

I was tasked with making a program that will make a PDF file with the figures requested by the input data. In this image we can see what the input data would be, i.e. size, gaps between shapes, type of shape, blueprint no. etc, and below what the actual diagram would look like.

[input data above and actual graphics below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtTcS.jpg)

It's very important for the project to use vector graphics, so I thought about using SVGs as they're really flexible and it's relatively easy to generate them programatically.
Then, I'm currently using a .NET library (Select.HtmltoPdf) to convert a HTML string to PDF, which is very convenient because designing PDFs directly in C# is a pain between the legs.
Using HTML gives me the advantage of using CSS and its something I'm relatively familiar with. The only disadvantage is that I can't render svgs directly using that library, I must first put them inside an html file.

The problem arises when I insert the SVG in the HTML and then render it to PDF using the library.
If I open the svg directly in say, Corel Draw or Adobe Illustrator, the dimensions are kept, and everything is as it should be. However, If I change the file's extension to .html and open it in Chrome, and then print to PDF, or render the PDF directly from my program, the shapes are scaled down slightly.

My question is how to keep the path's dimensions untouched while displaying them in an html page.

Here's my current .svg:

```svg
<svg x="0" y="0" width="215.9mm" height="279.4mm" viewBox="0 0 215.9 279.4">
<rect x="40" y="40" width="25" height="25" rx="1.5875" ry="1.5875" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill-opacity="1"/>
<ellipse cx="20" cy="20" rx="20" ry="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill-opacity="0"/>
</svg>
```

And the html I'm trying to use, which is basically the same svg with `<html>` tags around it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Style-Type" CONTENT="text/css" CHARSET="UTF-8"/>
<svg x="0" y="0" width="215.9mm" height="279.4mm" viewBox="0 0 215.9 279.4">
<rect x="40" y="40" width="25" height="25" rx="1.5875" ry="1.5875" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill-opacity="1"/>
<ellipse cx="20" cy="20" rx="20" ry="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill-opacity="0"/>
</svg>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not actually clear what you mean exactly by "the shapes are scaled down slightly".

But your problem is likely related to the fact that "215.9mm" in CSS, does not mean the same as a real world 215.9mm. The CSS value "1in" (or "25.4mm") is defined to be equivalent to 96 "CSS pixels".  It is up to the browser to decide how big that is rendered on screen, or when printed.

When the SVG is embedded in HTML, it is the browser that is deciding what "215.9mm" represents in the HTML page and the PDF generated from that.  Also don't forget it may also be deciding to scale its idea of the HTML page to fit what it thinks is the printer page size.

When your vector software generates the PDF, I expect it to be using a more accurate representation of those length values, based on your PDF size (be it A4 or whatever).